# json-ize string column in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have the following data structure:

```sql
create table test (tags VARCHAR, tags_json VARCHAR);

insert into test (tags, tags_json)
values ('A B', '["A", "B"]')
```

And I want to convert the column `tags` to a JSON column. If I were to do it with the `tags_json` column is pretty easy:

```sql
select tags_json::JSON from test
```

But when I run it using the `tags` column,

```sql
select tags::JSON from test
```

I get

```
SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
```

How can I convert the column `tags` to a JSON column in postgresql?

Comment: IS the problem that 'A B' is not valid JSON?

Comment: yes, that is what I think

Comment: What do you want to happen with the invalid JSON? What do you expect `'A B'` to be in a JSON representation?

Comment: the same as `'["A", "B"]'`

Comment: Are **all** values in that column space separated words?

Comment: yes, all words are separated by a space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first convert your "plain text" to an array, then you can use `to_jsonb()` to convert that to a proper JSON value:

```
select to_jsonb(regexp_split_to_array(tags, '\s+'))
from test;
```

If you want to permanently change the column's data type, you can use that expression in an ALTER statement:

```
alter table test
  alter tags type jsonb 
     using to_jsonb(regexp_split_to_array(tags, '\s+'));
```